# Python Plotly Dash 3D interactive data visualization web app duplicate callbacks

Tags: python, flask, visualization, plotly-dash

I am working on a complex visualization project using Dash. I hit a roadblock with a swapping feature due to duplcate callbacks. If anyone is available, let me know. I would like to discuss with them in more depth

Duplicate Callback Error solutions

Comment: Can help you out but please describe the details of your problem in your question. Provide as much specifics as you can, and actual source code (though not more than necessary). See the FAQ on here for "How to ask good questions" and use markdown formatting, etc.